Currently I am doing params.node.beans.gos.gridOptions.rowData, is there a better approach to get the gridOptions.rowData?
In older versions of ag-grid, I was able to access gridOptionsService from params.api.rowModel.gridOptionsService
In v30 and above it has been renamed to gos and I was able to access it from params.node.beans.gos
But, It was mentioned here, that beans are considered as internal api and using them there is no guarantee that it will be changed in each release.
So,is there a better way to get gridOptions.rowData other than from gos?
I tried to find any documention on beans, but was unable to find any resources.

It seems there is actually a better way to access gridOptions in latest ag-grid, using the getGridOption() method.
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-api/#reference-gridOptions-getGridOption
